# CSS overriding issue. Only font related lines are working

Tags: css, asp.net, telerik, hover

I am creating a menu using telerik:RadImageAndTextTile. I applied a custom skin following the instructions [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tilelist-tiles-appearance-tutorial-custom-skin.html)!. Follwing is the css code.

```
.RadTile_MyCustomSkin {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  /* Loading image */ }
  .RadTile_MyCustomSkin.rtileSelected {
    border-color: #666; }
  .RadTile_MyCustomSkin.rtileHovered {
    border-color: #9f9f9f; }
  .RadTile_MyCustomSkin.rtileSelected.rtileHovered {
    border-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.7); }
  .RadTile_MyCustomSkin.rtileSelected .rtileSelectedIcon {
    background-image: url('Tile/rtileSprite.png');
    _background-image: url('Tile/rtileSpriteIE6.png'); }
  html .RadTile_MyCustomSkin.RadTile h6.rtileTitle {
    color: #333333; }
  .RadTile_MyCustomSkin .rtilePeekContent {
    background-color: #eeeeee; }
  .RadTile_MyCustomSkin.rtileLoading,
  .RadTile_MyCustomSkin .rtileLoading {
    background-image: url('Common/loading_small.gif'); }
```

When I change the font size and color it works perfectly and changes the text format in the tile. But rest of the properties such as

> .RadTile_MyCustomSkin.rtileHovered {
>           border-color: #666; }

although I changed them, they are not affecting to the tile skin. Any idea on what is causing this problem? Thanks in advance

This is the web page code

```
<telerik:RadImageAndTextTile EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" Skin="MyCustomSkin"  ID="tlTrow_truck" runat="server" Shape="Square" BackColor="#f70000" ImageUrl="~/tiles/towtruck.png"
                Text="Tow Truck & Garage Services">                
 </telerik:RadImageAndTextTile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your selectors heavier, something is, most likely, overriding them (e.g., built-in rules). You can add a div for each rule:

```
        div.RadTile_MyCustomSkin.rtileHovered
        {
            border-color: blue;
        }

        div.RadTile_MyCustomSkin.rtileSelected.rtileHovered
        {
            border-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.7);
        }
```

Comment: I'll give it a try.Thnk u